# Style all siblings after anchor on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, siblings

I'm trying to style all nodes after a `<a>` when it is hovered.

The HTML code is

```
<a href="#">test</a>
<p>Is styles</p>
<p>Is not styled</p>
<p>Is not styled</p>
<p>Is not styled</p>
<p>Is not styled</p>
```

The CSS code is

```
a:hover + p {
    background: #ffbbff;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKvMw/). The problem is, that just the first sibling is styled. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong selector. `+` selects [adjacent siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). You need to use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~`:

```
a:hover ~ p {
    background: #ffbbff;
}
```

[See this demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/bKvMw/7/)

You can even combine these selectors if you want to:

```
a:hover ~ p {
    background: #ffbbff;
}

a:hover + p {
    background: #ffffbb;
}
```

[See this demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/bKvMw/8/)

Answer (score 3):

Try [~ (General sibling combinator)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)

```css
a:hover ~ p {
    background: #ffbbff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bKvMw/1/

Answer (score 1):

the `+` selects just the adjacent sibling. You want to use `~`

See [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) vs [General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

You need a general sibling selector, `+` is a adjacent sibling selector

Try this:

```
a:hover ~ p {
    background: #ffbbff;
}
```